# API callout from aura component using Jquery

Tags: api, aura, jquery

We have a API callout from aura component which gets invoked on a button press. Our org has about 150+ users using it. Nowadays , few users are complaining of API not getting called from aura components **intermittently**.[Checked from the server side , it does not get request] Is this some scaling issue or there is a limit on API callouts from Aura components.
Code used for calling api -

```
callApi : function(component,helper,jForm){
        let resource = component.get("v.resourceInfo");
        var urlEndpoint = resourceInfo['url'];
        $.ajax({
            url: urlEndpoint,
            data: jForm,
            isProcessData: false,
            isContentType: false,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            type: 'POST',
            headers:{
                "Authorization" : "Basic " + resource['api_key']
            },
            error: function(error) {
                component.set("v.error",error['statusText']);
                component.set("v.showSpinner",false);
            },
            success: function(data) {

                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              if(resourceInfo['user'] == undefined ){
                    let stringJson = JSON.stringify(obj['msg']['file']) ;
                    if(stringJson){
                        attachmentURL = '[' + stringJson + ']';
                    }
                } else {
                    let stringJson = JSON.stringify(obj['attachment']) ;
                    if(stringJson){
                        attachmentURL = '[' + stringJson + ']';
                    }
                }
                
            }
        });
    }
```

P.S. - code does not work in one of the production org but works everywhere else.

Comment: I don't think this is related to scaling issue or api limits at Salesforce org. There are no daily limits for outbound API callouts and since you are making the callouts from lightning component, [apex callout limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm) don't apply here. By `Checked from the server side`, did you mean you are able to check at the server were the service is hosted?

Comment: Are you able to replicate the problem? And, why use jQuery when you can get this done via Lightning/ Apex?

Comment: Yes, I checked from server where the service is hosted. Also, this code is in managed package and not able to replicate the issue elsewhere.

Comment: Regarding jQuery, this is legacy code in managed package due to which cannot change it or add logs.

Comment: Hard to point out the problem since this seems to be happening in only one of the production orgs. Are you able to replicate (I mean are you at least able to observe this behavior once in x # of callouts)? If yes, you could try reaching out Salesforce support and check if the callout was made in the first place (or if the server did not respond)?

Comment: As it's not working in one environment I am sure you are getting CSP error. Please go to set up and  check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/csp_trusted_sites.htm

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty , endpoint is added in CSP already. Also , this issue is intermittent i.e. it occurs in 2 out of 10 callouts. When the issue occurs , server does not receive request(checked from server side.)

Comment: @arut , This is observed in only one of the production orgs of customer which has installed our app.